# How do I send an e-mail with some non-ASCII characters in Python?

Tags: python, email, ascii

I am using Python 3.7 and trying to send e-mails with smtplib. My script works flawlessly so long as the message doesn't contain any Turkish characters such as "ş,ı,İ,ç,ö". The only solution I have found so far that works is using the `"string=string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')"` line but when I do that, the string "`İşlem tamamlanmıştır."` becomes `"lem tamamlanmtr."`.
So how can I keep the original string and bypass this error?

The relevant part of the code:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(r'smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, text)
server.sendmail(from, to, message)
server.close()
```

Comment: Did you try encoding it with `'utf-8'`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried "message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format("Yeni not bildirimi!", "İşlem tamamlanmıştır.").encode('utf-8')". This was the mail I got: "Ä°ÅŸlem tamamlanmÄ±ÅŸtÄ±r."

Comment: Looks like it's an encoding error... It decodes your `utf-8` encoded string using `cp1252`. For some other reason, you can't encode that message using `cp1252`, meaning it's basically a one way thing. If there's a way to specify the encoding in the message, you could try that.

Comment: The reason is that the message content doesn't have a `Content-type:` header, so the recipient basically guesses wildly. A different client would probably render it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

text_type = 'plain' # or 'html'
text = 'Your message body'
msg = MIMEText(text, text_type, 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = 'Test Subject'
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = 'user1@x.com,user2@y.com'
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
server.send_message(msg)
# or server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: I just included the relevant part of the code in the question, so when I do: msg.attach(MIMEText(text, text_type, 'utf-8')) and server.sendmail(from, to, msg), I get the error, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Comment: If the message has just a single part, putting it in a multipart container is obviously superfluous.

Comment: `text` should be a string without your encode/decode stuff.

Comment: @tripleee, That is true, I lifted this from code of mine that also supported adding attachments. But it will work.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson text is just a single sentence with no encode/decode stuff but I still get the same error.

Comment: Oh, i realize you are using a call to sendmail and not sendmsg. Let me edit my answer and fill out some more details.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Thank you so much. "server.send_msg(msg") returned the error "AttributeError: 'SMTP_SSL' object has no attribute 'send_msg'" but "server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())" did the job

Answer (score 3):

SMTP requires any non-ASCII content to be encapsulated and tagged properly. If you know what you are doing, this isn't hard to do by hand, but the simple and scalable solution is to use the Python `email` library to build a valid message to pass to `sendmail`.

This is adapted pretty much verbatim from the [Python `email` example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html). It uses the `EmailMessage` class which became official in 3.5, but should work as early as Python 3.3.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Create a text/plain message
msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(text)

msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = from
msg['To'] = to
```